# Keynote uses my 3 monitors, how can I get one back?

Tags: display, keynote

I am using Keynote (10.2, latest for now) for presentations. I love to have one monitor for displaying the content, one for displaying the notes, and have one free for chats, monitoring Q&A when on a webinar, and other apps. PowerPoint does that (migration to PowerPoint is not an option at this time).

When I start a presentation, Keynote takes control of the 3 screens. By default, one was just for the notes, but I re-designed the presenter mode, but now my third screen is a black screen. Is there a way to claim it back, or tell Keynote that there are only two monitors for it to access?